# C++ GUI Text Not Displaying

Tags: c++, qt

Basically I made a simple program to search a text file for a certain word. However my text file does not display in the textEdit Object it just displays it blank. I properly placed the text file into the resources and everything. I would really appreciate some input.

```
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>
#include "find.h"
#include "ui_find.h"

Find::Find(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Find)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); //sets up user interface
    getTextFile();
}

Find::~Find()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Find::on_goButton_clicked()
{
    QString word = ui->lineEdit->text(); //gets text and stores in word
    ui->textEdit->find(word, QTextDocument::FindWholeWords);
}

void Find::getTextFile()
{
    QFile myFile(":/textfile.txt"); //what file
    myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); //opens file

    QTextStream textStream(&myFile); //convert to stream
    QString line = textStream.readAll(); //store into variable
    myFile.close(); //close file

    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(line); //display text
    QTextCursor textCursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor(); //moves cursor into position
    textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1); //moves cursor into position

}
```

The application output also has this in red letters QIODevice::read: device not open

Comment: Isn't that `":/textfile.txt"` missing a starting `c` or something?

Comment: The path to the file starts with `:`, which indicates that the file is inside a resource file. If you don't have a `.qrc` file, then remove the `:` from the path.

Comment: I do have a qrc file though @koplersky

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that @rodrigo

Comment: Is `textfile.txt` inside a folder within the `.qrc` file?

Comment: Yes it is in the .qrc file @koplersky

Comment: What prefix have you set inside your `.qrc` file?

Comment: The prefix I have set is .txt

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator's clean rebuild are broken. Just permanently delete the kit specific folder where qmake has kept the project specific makefiles.

Attempt to do build again. rcc will be invoked specific to .qrc files added, that were skipped by older makefile files, as qmake has to give new makefile files now.

Comment: Thanks man, I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have Qt 5.4 and my code gave the same error, when it was working with MSVC2010 OpenGL as a compiler. I manually added MinGW 32bit to use it as compiler and it worked. 
P.S. I have not installed MSVC2013 for my Qt 5.4., and it works sometimes with MSVC2010 OpenGL without error, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added qrc file in project. If you use qrc file as external source, you should register it by call QResource::registerResource("path to file") in main function.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this with same error/symptoms. The issue was that I did not have a working compiler for my build kit. I ended up having to manually select my Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 11.0 (x86).  I guess it wasn't able to auto-detect it. This seems to be a common error message for new windows users beginning Qt5.